# Why is VBA macro deleting my table instead of inserting new row?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

```vb
Sub Save_Expense()
    Dim exDBrow As Long
    Dim exlstrow As Long

    exDBrow = ExpensesDB.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    exlstrow = Expenses.Range("B15").End(xlDown).Row
    
    With Expenses
        If .Range("B16").Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please Add Expenses Before Saving"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ExpensesDB.Range("A" & exDBrow & ":E" & exlstrow - 15) = .Range("B16:F" & exlstrow)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

I am trying to insert data from Worksheet("Expenses") into a table in Worksheet("ExpensesDB") using the above macro. When running the code, variable `Dim exDBrow as Long` is assigned value 894 and variable `Dim exlstrow as Long` is assigned value 16.

However, when I press play, all the data in Worksheet("ExpensesDB") (all 893 rows from Columns"A:E") goes to Mars. It's driving me nuts and I don't have a rocket ship to go after it. I am running Excel 365.

Comment: I found the problem. The ExpensesDB Range is the issue.
Should be
ExpensesDB.Range("A" & exDBrow & ":E" & exDBrow+exlstrow-15).Value

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider using [`Range.Resize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)

```vb
Sub Save_Expense()

    Dim exDBrow As Long, r As Long, arVal
    
    With expenses.Range("B15")
        If .Offset(1).Value = "" Then ' B16
            MsgBox "Please Add Expenses Before Saving"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' rows/values to copy
        r = .End(xlDown).Row - .Row
        arVal = .Offset(1).Resize(r, 5) ' B-F
    End With
    
    With expensesDB
        exDBrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & exDBrow).Resize(r, UBound(arVal, 2)) = arVal
    End With

End Sub
```